# Additional clause in GPL'd source code

Tags: licensing, gpl

I noticed this in the heading of some source code

```
  This core is written with the advise and consent of [author] and is
  released under the GNU Public License.  This core is freely available for
  use in any freeware project, subject to the following terms:

  Any modifications to this code must be duly noted in the source and
  approved by [author] and [maintainer] prior to public submission.
```

What are the implications of this clause in regards to the free-ness of the code?

Answer (score 5):

The GPL license specifically forbids additional clauses that restrict your rights, such as requiring permission before making your changes public.

Section 7 of the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) states:

> [...] All other non-permissive additional terms are considered “further restrictions” within the meaning of section 10. If the Program as you received it, or any part of it, contains a notice stating that it is governed by this License along with a term that is a further restriction, you may remove that term. [...]

This means that the approval clause is no more than a friendly request and can be ignored without violating the license.

---

If you don't want unauthorized versions of your open-source software to be released, then you must require that people who make modifications either submit them to your project for approval, or that they publish their fork under a different name.

Comment: The interaction between this clause and the right to licensors to apply any terms they want to the products they distribute is... interesting. I wouldn't rely on the notion that a court would uphold the suggestion of removing the term; a court could just as easily decide that the additional term was added afterwards and therefore takes precedence and it is section 7 that should be removed.  At the end of the day, this is a modified version of the GPL and therefore may or may not be interpreted the way the GPL was originally intended.

Comment: I would certainly suggest talking to a lawyer -- and preferably a copyright specialist -- before relying on the notion that you can just delete a term from somebody's licence because another part of the licence says you can.

Comment: @Jules: You can't just create a derived version of the GPL license and still call it GPL. That is in violation of the copyright on the license itself. And GPL section 7 doesn't prevent people from applying terms of their own by choosing a different license.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau But the code doesn't contain any copies of the GPL, modified or otherwise.  It just refers to it.  So there is no copyright violation.

Comment: Thank you Jules. That is probably best. It is old code and will likely not be a big deal, but this question could be helpful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for approval prior to publication of modifications render this licence non-free.  See for example, the [Debian Free Software Guidelines](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines), which requires licences to "allow modifications and derived works, and must allow them to be distributed under the same terms as the license of the original software."  As it wouldn't be possible to distribute the modification unless approval is obtained, this is not the case for this licence. Other definitions of free software also include similar text.